# Uitableview Sort with Hash Symbol in sectionIndexTitles

Tags: ios, uitableview, indexing, symbols

Here my code which i used to show the array of name using `sectionIndexTitlesForTableView`.The sorting is using Second name from the array.It showing only Alphabets,I need to show the last one (i.e Second name is null)as hash symbol.

Code:

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return [[[self.sections allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)] objectAtIndex:section];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return [[self.sections valueForKey:[[[self.sections allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)] objectAtIndex:section]] count];
}

- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
//How to add hash symbol here in last array
return [[self.sections allKeys]  sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
}
```

Nslog for

```
[[self.sections allKeys]  sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)]
```

(
    A,
    C,
    D,
    J,
    S,
    T,
    Q
)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this code-

```
NSSortDescriptor *descriptor =
                [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"your_key" ascending:YES selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];

                NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:descriptor];
```

Comment: Should i want to use this in inside sectionIndexTitlesForTableView ?

Comment: like this- 
    NSSortDescriptor *descriptor =
    [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"your_key" ascending:YES selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
    
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:descriptor];
    NSArray *sortedArray = [[self.sections allKeys] sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
    return sortedArray;

Comment: this is the key with which you want to sort. Like I have an array of names with "full_name" key. Then this will give me sorted names

Comment: i want to sort using last name...What happen if the last name was Null?